# SQL Sever: sum col in one table based on values in another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count

How can i Sum values in one table only if they exist in another.

eg
table1 - typeOfBiscuits

```
biscuits
jaffacakes
digestives

table2 - inventry
type number
digestives 2
digestives 3
jaffacakes 2
digestives 3
jaffacakes 4
cheesecake 1
```

Desired result of `select Count(number) from Inventry where type = <not sure how to get type from typeOfBisuit table>`

```
type count
digestives 8
jaffacakes 6
```

My attempt is as follows but i get a 'reference to multi part string' error

```
select Count(number) from Inventry where type = typeOfBiscuits.type
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT typeOfBiscuits.biscuits, Sum(Inventory.Number) as [Count]
FROM typeOfBiscuits INNER JOIN Inventory
ON typeOfBiscuits.biscuits = Inventory.type
GROUP BY typeOfBiscuits.type
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
 t1.Type,
 SUM(number) as [Count]
FROM
 inventry t1 INNER JOIN typeOfBiscuits t2 ON t1.Type=t2.Type
GROUP BY t1.Type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TYPE, 
       Sum(NUMBER) AS [Count] 
FROM   TABLE2 
WHERE  TYPE IN (SELECT TYPEOFBISCUITS 
                FROM   TABLE1) 
GROUP  BY TYPE
```